# python3: can't open file '/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker, and I tried to run django on the docker container.
However, after I ran the "docker-compose up -d" command the error

```
python3: can't open file '/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

shows in docker. Since it seems that the code can be run successfully in mac os, I doubt if it is the problem of Windows11 which I run the file currently.

My questions are:
1.Why the this error happens?
2.How I can fixed it?

The dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
```

the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The structure of my project directory:

```
├── project
|   ├──project
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── asgi.py
|       ├── setting.py
|       ├── urls.py
│       └── wsgi.py
|   ├── manage.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
└── requirements.txt
```

I've tried to solve the problem for hours, but the solutions I searched did not work. Hope someone can help. Thank you very much!!

Comment: can you please add the complete Docker file

Comment: please also add your tree (file structure) of your directory

Comment: The error is self explanatory: when running your image, the file manage.py is not at the workdir you have declared so it cannot be found. This is a very classic one and should be solve by inspecting the content of your image: `docker run -it image bash` and inspect your filesystem.

Comment: @ArunbhYashaswi above are the complete docker file

Comment: @Divyessh Thanks. I've add the file structure of my directory above.

Comment: @jlandercy I would like to ask how can I run the command while the container is on "exited" status.

Answer (score 3):

Your Dockerfile is copying the current directory tree into the image's `/app` directory, which is pretty normal.  When the Compose `command:` override runs, you're still in that `/app` directory, but your application code is in a `project` subdirectory.

You should be able to see this launching temporary containers to look at the built filesystem in the image, like

```bash
docker-compose run web ls
docker-compose run web ls ./project
```

There are a couple of ways to approach this ([@Divyessh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73924344) should work as well) but the most straightforward might be to make the `project` subdirectory be the current directory when running the container.  It's also a little better practice to put the `CMD` in the Dockerfile, so that you could independently `docker run` the image without its Compose setup.

```bash
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app              # creates the directory, don't need to RUN mkdir
COPY requirements.txt ./  # shorter and safer to COPY into current directory
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./ ./

# add the following
WORKDIR /app/project      # switch to project subdirectory
EXPOSE 8000               # document container-side port
CMD python3 ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000  # standard command to run
```

In your `docker-compose.yml` file you don't need the `command:` (it's the same as the Dockerfile `CMD`) or `volumes:` block (which will cause the code in the image to be ignored and replaced with something else) and I'd delete these lines.

```yaml
version: '3.8'  # "3" means "3.0"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your docker-compose file command like this because the manage.py file is present in the project folder.

```
version: '3'
services:
web:
    build: .
    command: python3 project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 0):

change in your docker-compose file

to:-

```
 volumes:
      - .:/app
```

this:-

```
volumes:
      - /app
```

Answer (score 0):

removing worked for me

```
 volumes:
  - .:/app
```

but this will not allow see real time changes, currently looking into it...

Comment: Yep, mounting a volume is what causes the files to update inside the container. Without a mount, you just get the files that were baked into the image.